# Does there exist a way for retailers to send a digital copy of the receipt to a users phone via NFC?

Tags: android, nfc

I'm not sure if this is the correct stack exchange sub-site to post this on, but I figured stack overflow would be fine. Now, does there exist a way such that a retailer can send a digital copy of a receipt to a customer when that customer pays at an NFC enabled terminal using Android Pay. I figure this would not be a terribly difficult thing to implement if it does not already exist, but is it something a person could feasibly implement without being the person working at Google in charge of these services.

Sorry for this type of question, if you know a better place for me to put it let me know.

Thanks!

Ps: Assuming there is nothing in my power to do, What are the chances that if I ask very nicely Google would implement this. :)

Edited to remove mentions to IOS because I figure IOS won't let me do this, if you know anything pertaining to IOS feal free to respond

Comment: Not with ApplePay and None. The retailer would need to ask the purchaser for an email address and deliver the receipt from their back end system.  With ApplePay neither the merchant nor Apple have access to the card number, only the card provider knows which account was actually charged.

Comment: I don't think Apple exposes the NFC API to third parties. As PaulW says, ApplePay transactions are not exposed at all. Now you could implement something using BLE, but you'd need to encrypt it since the range of BLE is > 10 meters.